# Bootbox alert displaying at bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootbox

I have recently been tasked with updating my companies javascript alerts with the more customizable bootbox alerts. After messing around with it some, I have gotten an alert to appear on click of a button, however the alert appears at the bottom of the screen - so far at the bottom it extends the height of the page.

This previous question is very similar to mine: [Bootbox alert displaying in the top right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091169/bootbox-alert-displaying-in-the-top-right) though not exactly. I have already tried all the solutions from there, and made sure to mess around with the values myself. One of the solutions was this:

```
.modal-dialog {
        left: auto;
    }
```

And I notice with the left keyword affects the pop up, but top/bottom do not.
This is the code I am currently using(plus the includes, not shown)

```
<div>
    <button class ="btn btn-danger">Alert Box</button>
</div>

<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('.btn').on('click', function(){
            bootbox.prompt({
                title: "This is a prompt, vertically centered!", 
                centerVertical: true,
                callback: function(result){ 
                    console.log(result); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

My bootbox.min.js version in v5.5.2
and my bootstrap.min.js is v5.0.2, though I did briefly try and swtich bootstrap to v4.X, and nothing changed

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find the solution, or at least a work around. Was able to modify the bootbox div using the margin-top:

```
.bootbox{
    margin-top:-500px;
}
```

And that moved it 500px down from the top of the screen instead of forcing it down to the bottom

Comment: Just a note: `centerVertical: true` adds the `.modal-dialog-centered` class to the modal - if you're seeing the modal way down the page, I'd suspect that your page is taller than the viewport and one or more rules are causing the overlay to stretch that whole height, rather than just the viewport.